# console.log not working when running an Android app in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have a basic Cordova application with a simple `console.log()` function at the end.

My index.html file looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("Device is ready!");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it's basically the same as the automatically generated file with some `console.log` script at the bottom.

Unfortunately when I run the app on Android using `cordova emulate android`, I cannot seem to find the output from `console.log(..)` anywhere. However, it works fine on browsers.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: No I ran it using the command line. I have it installed though

Comment: if you run your project from android studio you can find the console.log in the logcat window

Comment: How do I run a Cordova application in Andriod Studio?

Comment: If you want to run your application on Android Studio then you have to search for "import cordova project to android studio" its straightforward

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(..)`only works on browser console, not on command line.

To get log that appears on your app use `alert(...);`.

Anyway if you wanted to see your logs by `consol.log()` you should use an IDE like Android Studio or use `ddms` located where your `adb` is installed. (run `ddms.bat`)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
```

This plugin will enable console logging.

It has various methods for console printing

1. console.log
2. console.error
3. console.exception
4. console.warn
5. console.info
6. console.debug
7. console.assert
8. console.dir
9. console.dirxml
10. console.time
11. console.timeEnd
12. console.table

By default plugin is not installed so you will have to add it manually.

[Reference](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console).

Regards.

Comment: I have installed it, but it still dosent work on Andriod!